# "instant repository" concept in Spring Hibernate JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am reading doc about Spring Framework and I read the concept of "instant repository" related to Spring Data. See last question of
http://golijava.blogspot.be/2015/11/spring-hibernate-jpa.html
but I couldn't find information anywhere

Comment: Can you add the link for the doc you are referring to

Comment: The posted link contains sample questions from the [Core Spring Certification](https://pivotal.io/training/courses/core-spring-training).  The term "instant repository" seems to be covered during the four-day training programme for the certification but is not defined anywhere else with authority. The [official guide for the certification](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=9ojJDQAAQBAJ&q=instant+repository#v=snippet&q=instant%20repository&f=false) seems to indicate that it refers to extending the `Repository` interface and letting the Spring Data infrastructure generate the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not familiar with that term,  I believe it has to do with the generation of the repository implementations during the Spring container startup. The thing is that when using Spring Data it is enough to define a Repository interface adhering to the specific rules (for common tasks) while the actual implementation will be generated by the Spring Data during the container initialization.

An example of an actual repository could be the following interface definition :

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

}
```

You may find detailed information about Spring Data and in particular about it's repositories by following this link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 3):

Instant Repository is a term used in Spring Data.
You create Instant Repository with these two steps
1. Annotate Domain class
2. Define your repository as an interface by extending Repository interface.

Spring will implement instant repository at run time as it scans for all the interface extending springs Repository